# Provide a way to search for a user's answers to closed questions

Tags: feature-request, search, deleted-questions, closed-questions

The only notification one gets that a question they've answered has met with others' dissatisfaction is when it has been deleted and their reputation is reduced. It would be nice if a user, who has gone to the effort to answer a question, would either be notified that it has been closed, or at least be able to search for closed questions that they've answered. This way, they would be given a chance to improve the question before it is considered for deletion.

I would like to request

1. Each user who has answered a question that is subsequently closed be notified of the closure.
2. There be a way to search for closed or deleted questions that a particular user has answered.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/266734/my-answers-to-closed-questions though hopefully it won't just be a way to reopen everything one has answered without improving the question first.

Comment: Thanks; I am aware of that, but that is not always up to date. I would like a method that is within the site.

Comment: One could do allmost all this via favorites (especially if one does not use them for much else).

Comment: @quid: are you suggesting that we favorite every question we answer? I use the favorites for other things and this would add noise to that.

Comment: I want this, mainly so I can save the content for future reference in case of deletion. Why aren't we allowed to search for deleted questions anyway?

Comment: I did not suggest anything; I pointed out that one could do something (and had even added a condition). However, if one wants to follow the fate of a thread, the feature for that is favorites. If one does not want to follow the fate of a thread, then well one does not want to follow it. Frankly, I am really undecided if I want to be notified of closures of each and every question I answered.

Comment: +1 These and further capabilities are essential in order to track deletions. For example, last night all of the community deletions completely overflowed the short 10k deletion queue, so there is no way for anyone (except SE employees) to know what other questions may have also been deleted. The lack of such checks and balances makes the platform ripe for abuse. It is absolutely absurd that there is no way to track deletions. Already this loophole has been exploited to delete thousands of posts, some of which had valuable answers and most likely would be undeleted if not hidden by the platform

Comment: @Bill: Your comment seems to be also closely related to this feature request to improve the tools for recently deleted questions:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124420/improve-the-recently-deleted-tool (which I am in favor of)

Comment: Could you please clarify 2. Do you mean that each user can search for *their* answers (and their answers only)? This is not really what is written in my opinion, but it is the only way I can make sense of "a particular user" being stressed.

Comment: @quid: I figured that the easiest place to add such a function would be in the "Advanced Search" options. Currently, we can search for all closed questions, but we cannot narrow that down by specifying someone who has answered the question. It would be nice if we could look for answers by any specific user, but if it is only possible to search for one's own answers, that would be better than what we have now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I agree about the search. Indeed, the first thing I tried when reading your proposal is try if "closed:yes" and "is:answer" can be combined (where the "closed" would be taken from the question-post obviously). This could be useful. To focus/restrict on "per user" searches seems not that desirable to me (restriction to "self" is a special case); indeed, a more useful search than answers of a given user to me would seem, say, answers scored +5 to closed questions.

Comment: These would be cool features.

Comment: +1. At least one post about *closed questions* that is about *construction* instead of *destruction*.

Comment: [This f-r on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209096/notify-answerers-that-a-question-theyve-answered-is-in-trouble) seems somewhat related.

Comment: @quid: It does, and I have upvoted that request. Thanks.